# Vagrant virtual hosts/shared folders not accessible

Tags: php, apache, centos, vagrant, virtual-machine

I currently have a vagrant box with CentOS 7. In my Vagrantfile I have the following configurations:

```sh
config.vm.box = "centos/7"
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
# config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
```

I know that by default, vagrant shares the contents of the folder that contains the Vagrantfile. Those can be reached on the `/vagrant` folder inside the VM.

The code I want to reach is inside the same folder of the same folder as the Vagrantfile. I can reach it inside the VM on `/vagrant/api/`.

My goal is to be able to reach the index of the api inside my machine. I'm trying to create a virtual host for this effect.

On my provision file I have the following:

```sh
if [ $(grep -c 'api' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) -eq 0 ]; then
cat >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf <<EOM
<VirtualHost *:8081>    
    DocumentRoot "/vagrant/api/public"
    <Directory "/vagrant/api/public">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, UPDATE"
        Header merge  Vary "Origin"
    </Directory> 

    ServerName vagrant.api.local:8081
    ServerAlias vagrant.api.local
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</VirtualHost>
EOM
fi

service httpd restart;
```

And I added `192.168.50.4 vagrant.api.local` to both `/etc/hosts` file (on my machine and on the VM).

Yet, when I try to access `vagrant.api.local:8081` on the browser I get `This site can’t be reached. vagrant.api.local refused to connect.`

I can ping this url and get positive results, 0% packet loss.

Any idea on how can I load the `/vagrant/api/public/index.php` file on this url? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I will answer on this

> My goal is to be able to reach the index of the `api` inside my machine

so you're correct by default, vagrant shares the content of your local folder containing the `Vagrantfile` with the `/vagrant` folder of the VM.

One thing though is that box an override the configuration of the Vagrantfile, and its the case of the `centos/7` box.

If you look in your `$HOME/.vagrant.d/boxes/centos-VAGRANTSLASH-7/<box_version>/virtualbox` you will find the box Vagrantfile which declares

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.base_mac = "525400261060"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
end
```

As the folder is of type [rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html) its only *one-time one-way sync from the machine running to the machine being started by Vagrant.*

The easiest for you is to remove the rsync folder type and use default virtualbox sync folder mechanism which will provide (near) real-time bi-directional synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did remove the `rsync`. Accessing `192.168.50.4` will show me the apache page, but the `vagrant.api.local:8081` still gives me `Site cannot be reached. vagrant.api.local refused to connect.` Any idea on how can I fix this? http://vagrant.api.local redirects me to the apache page also.

Comment: did you try replace `ServerName vagrant.api.local:8081` with `ServerName 0.0.0.0:8081` and also does it work within the VM ?